# How to change the .ispac file name In SSIS 2012?

Tags: ssis

Once I build the SSIS solution, an .ispac file is generated with a name I want to change, however I do not know how to do it.

[image: .ispac file]

Comment: This is the name of your Integration Services Project, you can just rename your project inside Visual Studio

Comment: Tks @Kobi, I could find where to make the change: Properties/Common Properties/Project/Identification/Name